# How do I solve this probability problem with Probability?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

> Consider a stick of length 1. Pick two points uniformly at random on
>   the stick, and break the stick at those points. What is the
>   probability that the three segments obtained in this way form a
>   triangle?

I have implemented two versions. Version 1 works correctly, but version 2 doesn't. How can I fix the second version?

#### Version 1

```
Module[{min,  max},
  {min, max} = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ RandomReal[1, {10^5, 2}] // Transpose;
  Mean@MapThread[
    Function[{x, y, z}, N@Boole[x + y > z && x + z > y && y + z > x]],
    {min, max - min, 1 - max}]]
```

#### Version 2

```
Block[{t1, t2, t3},
  t1 = {x > 0, y > 0, x + y < 1};
  t2 = {x + y > z, x + z > y, y + z > x} /. z -> 1 - x - y;
  Print[t3 = And @@ t1 ~ Join ~ t2 // FullSimplify];
  Probability[t3,
    Distributed[x,  UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]] &&
    Distributed[y,  UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]]
```

Comment: I think you are mixing up the "coordinate" of the breaking point with the length of the resulting stick segment. The length of the resulting stick segment is y-x, not y. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676/probability-that-a-stick-randomly-broken-in-two-places-can-form-a-triangle by the way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the "coordinate" of the breaking point with the length of the resulting stick segment. The length of the resulting stick segment is y-x, (if y>x) not y. If we want x and y to be uniformly distributed, it is is useful to think in terms of the length of the leftmost stick segment l1=Min[x,y] and the length of the center stick segment which is l2=Max[x,y]-Min[x,y] (=Abs[x-y])

This seems to be what you want

```
Block[{t1, t2, t3},
 t1 = {1 > x > 0, 1 > y > 0};
 t2 = {Min[x, y] + (Max[x, y] - Min[x, y]) > z, 
    Min[x, y] + z > (Max[x, y] - Min[x, y]), (Max[x, y] - Min[x, y]) +
       z > Min[x, y]} /. z -> 1 - Max[x, y];
 Print[t2];
 Print[t3 = And @@ t1~Join~t2 // FullSimplify];
 Probability[t3, 
  Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]] && 
   Distributed[y, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]]
```

-> 1/4

Possibly the following is nicer

```
Block[
 {t1, t2, t3, x, y, l1, l2, l3},
 t1 = {1 > x > 0, 1 > y > 0};
 t2 = {l1 + l2 > l3, l1 + l3 > l2, l2 + l3 > l1} /. {l1 -> Min[x, y], 
    l2 -> Abs[x - y], l3 -> 1 - Max[x, y]};
 Print[t3 = And @@ t1~Join~t2 // FullSimplify];
 Probability[t3, 
  Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]] && 
   Distributed[y, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]]
```

-> 1/4

Comment: Yep - you're right (and beat me to it:) ). Can also be simplified to one condition `t = {0 < x < 1/2, 1/2 < y < 1, 1 - x - y < 1/2};`

Comment: `Probability[t3, 
 Distributed[{x, y}, UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]]` is it right?

Comment: @chyanog yeah I think so. It only puts emphasis on the independence of x and y I think, they are independently generated anyway so it does not matter. gpap I like your observation :). Next time u beat me :)

Answer (score 15):

Amazingly, **the most direct and mindless possible approach works instantaneously**.

Start by **characterizing the valid side lengths**: each side is the shortest distance between its endpoints; the path made by the other two sides cannot be any shorter.

```
triangleQ[x_, y_, z_] := x <= y + z && y <= z + x && z <= x + y;
```

**Break the stick** uniformly and independently at locations $u_1$ and $u_2$:

```
f = UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
```

[image: Unit line]

Noting that the breaks (from left to right) create pieces of length $\min(u_1,u_2)$, $|u_2-u_1|$, and $1 - \max(u_1, u_2)$, **request the probability** that the pieces form a triangle:

```
Probability[triangleQ[Min[u1, u2], Abs[u2 - u1], 1 - Max[u1, u2]], {u1, u2} \[Distributed] f ]
```

> $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: +1, I like mindless solutions. That's why we have MMA right? I'd name `triangleQ` differently, the `Q` makes me think it can only return `True` or `False`

Comment: @Rojo (Apart from `True` or `False`, what else could `triangleQ` return (assuming it is passed three nonnegative real numbers)?)  Your comment about mindless solutions is a penetrating one: "mindless" translates to "easily seen to be a correct implementation of the question," which satisfies the Prime Directive of *getting the right answer above all else.*

Comment: Nothing else, but predicates seem to not be symbolic functions. Compare `Equal` to `SameQ`. And here `triangleQ` is being used as symbolic. I'm not sure what "penetrating" means in this context. It's a disturbing word

Comment: @Rojo "Penetrating," in its metaphorical use here, means "going into the substance of the matter."

Answer (score 13):

Each uniform divides the stick into a smaller and a longer side. If the smaller side of both uniforms coincide (left-left, or right-right) then you won't have a triangle because the rightmost/leftmost division will be longer than 0.5. The odds of this happening is 1/2.
If they don't coincide, then you will have a triangle only when the sum of the smallest sides is higher than 0.5. So,

```
1/2 Probability[
  x + y < 1/2, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
    TransformedDistribution[Min[z, 1 - z], 
     z \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]] // Thread]

(* 1/4 *)
```

By the way

```
With[{min := Min[x, y], max := Max[x, y]}, 
 RegionPlot[
  And @@ Thread[0 < {x, y} < 1] && 
   Max[min, max - min, 1 - max ] < 1/2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `OrderDistribution` (to get the joint distribution of `Min` and `Max` in a sample of size 2 from a standard Uniform distribution) combined with a simpler condition:

```
dist = OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[], 2}, {1,2}]; 
Probability[y > 1/2 && 1/2 > y - x && 1/2 > x, Distributed[{x, y}, dist]]
(* 1/4 *)
Probability[Max[x, y - x, 1 - y] < 1/2, Distributed[{x, y}, dist]] (* thanks: Rojo *)
(* 1/4 *)
```

Comment: @Rojo, thank you.

Comment: This has my symbolic accept

Comment: `Max[x, y - x, 1 - y] < 1/2` is a nice alternative notation for the condition

Answer (score 1):

This is just a variant of Rojo's argument.

If one considers the lengths of the segments rather than the points then:

```
Probability[
 x + y > 1/2 && x < 1/2 && y < 1/2 \[Conditioned] 
  x + y < 1, {x, y} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[2]]
```

yielding 1/4

You can see this as follows:

```
FullSimplify@
 Reduce[x + y + z == 1 && x + y > z && x + z > y && y + z > x && 
   x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

gives:

```
2 x < 1 && x + y > 1/2 && 2 y < 1 && x + y + z == 1
```

A little fun:

```
c = x + y > 1/2 && x < 1/2 && y < 1/2;
rp = RegionPlot[{x + y < 1, c}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {LightRed, LightBlue}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
tf[p_] := Module[{u, v, tg},
  {u, v} = p;
  tg = Quiet[SSSTriangle[u, v, 1 - u - v]] /. 
    SSSTriangle[__] :> Text["Does not form a triangle", {0.5, 0.5}];
  Graphics[tg, PlotRange -> Table[{0, 1}, 2], Frame -> True, 
   ImageSize -> 300]]
Manipulate[
 Row[{Show[rp, Graphics[Point[pt]]], tf@pt}],
 {{pt, {0.4, 0.4}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  This is what interactive displays are all about.

Comment: @JimBaldwin thanks. Hope you got a good nights sleep. :)